# Need to ensure only 1 thread accessing resource

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class with an action listener (as part of a JSF managed bean). The code inside action listener is creating a new object of another class. Class A.
This object is being used to invoke a function of this class ..

```
public void invokeActionListener(ActionEvent act)
{
MyClass myclass=new MyClass();
myclass.invokeRequest();
}
```

invokeRequest function in turn after processing some data invoke another function B. The function B invoke another function C. C invoke D and then the flow finishes..

I want to ensure that when invokeRequest should be invoked only once till the complete flow till D finishes.

I put synchronize on function invokeRequest() but synchronize is not working. Different threads are able to invoke this function even when 1 thread is still working.

```
Class MyClass
{
public synchronized void invokeRequest()
{
 invokeRequestB();
}

public void invokeRequestB()
{
invoke RequestC();
}

public void invokeRequestC()
{
invoke RequestD();
}

public void RequestD()
{
//Complete processing and end the flow.
}
```

Please guide.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The synchronized methods use their respective objects for locking. If you need to prevent synchronize calls in *different* objects, you still need to use the same object for synchronizing. One way to do is using a static field for the synchronizing:

```
Class MyClass {
    private static final Object lock = new Object();

    public void invokeRequest() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            invokeRequestB();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Or you can use `MyClass.class` as the monitor object; use whatever you find more readable.

Comment: But what will be the scope of this object Lock..??..I mean on every click of a button on page I am creating a new object of MyClass and in turn invoking invokeRequest function with this new object. I understood that since everytime a new object is being fed into Synchronize block the thread is not acquiring any lock. But what might be the useful purpose of using a static final object Lock for this class...No clue....!!..

Comment: All instances of the class share the static var instance. That's why static vars are also referred to as "Class variables".

Comment: @AngelsandDemons In your sample code the calls use the objects themselves for locking, but since every click creates a new one, many calls can run in parallel. Using a static field (or the class) for synchronizing results in only one `invokeRequest()` being run at a time, *in any MyClass instance*. (that's what I understood you wanted, if it's not, I'll delete the answer)

Comment: @kiheru Indeed. Thats what I wanted. I am actually confused.. That is why posted a comment. So if I create a new object of Class C inside invokeRequestB() function and use this new object to access function of Class C do I again need to put Synchronize inside the Class C and create a static object in Class C..??..

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve. If you dont want that MyClass and C methods could be executed parallel, you need the static Object of MyClass for the synchronize in Class C.

Comment: @AngelsandDemons The synchronization in my code snippet prevents more than one thread entering the block at a time (that is, calling `invokeRequestB()`). So you should not need any more locking, assuming all the access to the resource you want to protect goes througn `invokeRequest()`. (`invokeRequestB()` etc should be `private` to ensure that they're not called elsewhere, or they need to use `synchronized (lock)` too).

Comment: Understood. Thanks for providing such an apt explanation..!!